# Add a tag to the list in the DataFrame based on the data from the second DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-spark

I have two DataFrames - the first one with the columns model, cnd, age, tags (this is a repeatable field - String list/array), min, max and the second one with the main_model column.
I would like to add the MAIN tag to the first DataFrame to the tags list if the **model field value** from this DataFrame coincides with any model from DataFrame with main models. The code is written in Scala.
Example below:

```
INPUT:
DataFrame no1
+------+-----+----+-------+------+-----+
| model| cnd | age| tags  |  min | max |
+------+-----+----+-------+------+-----+
|  foo1|   xx|  10|  []   |   1  |  2  |
|  foo2|   yy|  20|  []   |   2  |  3  | 
|  foo3|   zz|  30|  []   |   3  |  4  | 
+------+-----+----+-------+------+-----+

DataFrame no 2 - list for verifying models from the first DataFrame

+-----------+
| main_model|
+-----------+
|  foo1     |
|  foo3     | 
|  foo5     | 
+-----------+


 OUTPUT:

+------+-----+----+-------+------+-----+
| model| cnd | age| tags  |  min | max |
+------+-----+----+-------+------+-----+
|  foo1|   xx|  10|[MAIN] |   1  |  2  |
|  foo2|   yy|  20|  []   |   2  |  3  | 
|  foo3|   zz|  30|[MAIN] |   3  |  4  | 
+------+-----+----+-------+------+-----+
```

I haven't been able to find a reasonable solution.
So far Im trying with:

```
    dataFrame1.join(dataFrame2, dataFrame1("model") === dataFrame2("main_model"), "left_outer") .select(
dataFrame1("model"),
dataFrame1("cnd"),
dataFrame1("age"),
when(dataFrame2("main_model").isNotNull, concat(dataFrame1("tags"), lit(", MAIN"))).otherwise(dataFrame1("tags")).alias("tags"),
dataFrame1("min"),
dataFrame1("max")
)
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Looks to me relatively easy by just doing left join with second data frame and adding MAIN to tags if main_model is not null.

Comment: Hi, I just edited question with my solution so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, you can use array_union instead of concat

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val data = Seq(("foo1","xx",10,Array[String](),1,2),
               ("foo2","yy",20,Array[String](),2,3),
               ("foo3","zzxx",30,Array[String](),3,4))
val df = data.toDF("model","cnd","age","tags","min","max")
val modelData = Seq(("foo1"),("foo3"),("foo5"))
val modelDf = modelData.toDF("main_model")

val joinedDf = df.join(modelDf, df("model") === modelDf("main_model"), "left")
joinedDf.select(
  df("model"),
  df("cnd"),
  df("age"),
  when(modelDf("main_model").isNotNull, array_union(df("tags"), lit(Array("MAIN")))).otherwise(df("tags")).alias("tags"),
  df("min"),
  df("max")
).show
```

And the output:

```
+-----+----+---+------+---+---+
|model| cnd|age|  tags|min|max|
+-----+----+---+------+---+---+
| foo1|  xx| 10|[MAIN]|  1|  2|
| foo2|  yy| 20|    []|  2|  3|
| foo3|zzxx| 30|[MAIN]|  3|  4|
+-----+----+---+------+---+---+
```